# Can someone help me identify this dried tree?

Tags: identification, trees

Can someone help me to identify the dried tree on the following image?
Any info where I can get it would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a picture of a real tree.

Comment: @Nail C., I do think it could be a picture of a real tree, like e.g. some sort of Juniperus. Under some crazy growth circumstance... look at that one: http://krapooarboricole.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/genc3a9vrier-de-limbut-11.jpg

Comment: It is likely a dead juniper. I too fail to see what the relevance to gardening & landscaping,

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not a photograph so it could just be something the artist made up. In fact it's an artist rendering for some apartments in Marina Del Ray, CA. https://www.openlistings.com/p/4080-glencoe-avenue-305-marina-del-rey-ca-90292

My guess is it's not a supposed to be a tree but rather tree branches. That's normally what I see in this form.

You may want to look at Manzanita branches or sage trees. It's not exactly the same and maybe it required special care to get this form. Found this site which might be useful. https://www.decorativebranches.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1817

You may also want to see if you can find the artist and ask if he has any info. If such a piece actually exists I have a feeling it might not be something you can get at the above website for a few bucks but more of an art piece or a very rare find.

It's very nice though.